# how can i concatenate the string in "for clause"?

Tags: python

```
filecontents = f.read()
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(filecontents)

for sentence in sent_tokenize_list:
    sentence = "Start " + sentence + " End"
    print sentence
```

this results like

```
"start ~~~~~~ end "
"start ~~~~~ end"
"start ~~~~~ end"
```

but I want to concatenate them all, as a whole string. how can I do it.

Comment: Do you want start AllSentencesHere end or start - sentence - end + start - sentence - end etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and join method on an empty string to join all of the sentences.

```
print "".join(["Start " + sentence + " End" for sentence in sent_tokenize_list])
```

You can also use a generator comprehension as mentioned in the comments for better performance.

`print "".join("Start " + sentence + " End" for sentence in sent_tokenize_list)`

Comment: Quick optimization: you can remove the `[]` to use a generator instead. I think it's a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
" ".join(["Start " + sentence + " End" for sentence in sent_tokenize_list])
```

Comment: I don't want to add just one "start" and "end" in the text. for each sentence, add "start" and "end".

Comment: In that case you have answers from other people. Your question was not very clear then.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add each processed sentence to the result, like this

```
result = ''
for sentence in sent_tokenize_list:
    result += "Start " + sentence + " End"
print result
```

Alternatively (and in a more pythonic way as i feel it) you can use list comprehension instead of for clause to make a list of modified sentences and then just join all the sentences together

```
new_sentences = ['Start ' + sentence + ' End' for sentence in sent_tokenize_list]
result = ''.join(new_sentences)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a *list comprehension*:

```
result = "".join("Start {} end".format(sentence) for sentence in sent_tokenize_list)
```

Comment: You forgot to add brackets.

Comment: @user161151 not needed, try and check :)

Comment: Didn't know generator expressions existed.

Comment: No, but 1. Without them it's not strictly a list comprehension and 2. It's more efficient to join a list than an iterator.